# What's the meanings for each lines in public part of the Class?

Tags: c++

Here's the code in Message.h:

```
 class Message
{
 private:
 protected:
 public:
 std::string content;
 Message(std::string arg_s) { content = arg_s; }
 void setContent(std::string arg_s) { content = arg_s; }
 std::string getContent(void) { return content; }
};
```

Actually, this is one of header files which are used to convert a JSON message to C++ objects. This header file would take the "message" key from the JSON.

So for this header file, how it works to convert in C++ object? (I try to develop cpp code for this h file).